# What is the best time to water the garden?

Tags: watering, grass

What is the best time for gardening? How many times should we water the garden?

- I have grass and some plants (I don't know their names). I am just interested in nourishing the grass which is growing very slowly and not getting very green. I have supplied the grass and plants with vermicompost and NPK 17-17-17 complex fertilizers. I do not know these fertilizers well, I just did what the gardener requested.
- The garden is in India and I am not sure how to describe the weather for you now.

Comment: This question is really too broad to answer in any meaningful way. Could you update with more information? What type of garden do you want to water? What types of plants are you growing? What climate are you in? If you update your question with more specifics, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more information, probably Insta's answer on watering is the way to go, but I want to ask about your grass - you say you're feeding it with a 17-17-17 fertiliser - unless you want to encourage the grass to flower, that's not the right formulation - grass, if it needs any feed at all at this stage, should be a nitrogen rich formula, principally, something more like 12-4-8.

Comment: I agree. Grass, compared with most garden plants, needs a fertilizer with a high-N ratio.

Answer (score 4):

The question is very vague, but in general:

Slow watering for a long period (like with a soaker hose) will allow the water to percolate deeper in the soil, and plants will send roots downward seeking it out.  Not all plants have the ability to do this, so more details are necessary.

Watering in the morning will give ample time for the water to soak, before the mid-day sun hits.  Watering in the middle of the day will cause the water to evaporate almost immediately (plants do not need "cooling bursts of water" as people do, they are more than capable of respiring given adequate water in the soil).  Watering at night may allow for mold growth overnight, given a long cool period.

Also, 5 seconds on Google showed me the weather in India is currently hot and humid (there's a shocker).  Based on this, I would do the following:

- Two hours of an oscillating sprinkler, watering from 6AM - 8AM to cover the grass, Monday, Wednesday, and Saturday.  Run a soaker hose during this time in the garden.